# Getting variables with function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I want to know if its possible to get a variable thats within the parent function each time a child function is called.

```
// Will alert the different variable within each parent function
function GetVariableEach() {
   alert(eachVar);
}


function function1() {
   var eachVar = "1";
   GetVariableEach();
}

function function2() {
   var eachVar = "2";
   GetVariableEach();
}

function function3() {
   var eachVar = "3";
   getVariableEach();
}
```

So that should alert 3 times, and each time it will alert with its corresponding variable, obviously this is an example and not working code.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible since eachVar is local. That's the point of passing parameters to the function i.e.:

```
function GetVariableEach(myVar) {
    alert(myVar);
}


function function1() {
   var eachVar = "1";
   GetVariableEach(eachVar);
}

function function2() {
   var eachVar = "2";
   GetVariableEach(eachVar);
}

function function3() {
   var eachVar = "3";
   GetVariableEach(eachVar);
}
```

Check this for more info about function parameters http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass a parameter to your `GetVariableEach` function. There's a couple ways to do this, but from your code and your request, here's a direction you could take:

```
function GetVariableEach(theVar) {
    alert(theVar);
}

function function1() {
    var eachVar = "1";
    GetVariableEach(eachVar);
}
function function2() {
    var eachVar = "2";
    GetVariableEach(eachVar);
}
function function3() {
    var eachVar = "3";
    GetVariableEach(eachVar);
}
```

Alternatively, you could just make an array of your functions and cycle through them to obtain your variable:

```
function function1() {
    var eachVar = "1";
    return eachVar;
}
function function2() {
    var eachVar = "2";
    return eachVar;
}
function function3() {
    var eachVar = "3";
    return eachVar;
}

function getAllFunctionValues() {
    var functionArray = [function1(), function2(), function3()];

    for (var i = 0; i < functionArray.length; i++) {
        alert(functionArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, you asked for jQuery (I don't think you need it). But if you want it, here's a basic example of jQuery:

```
function function1() {
    var eachVar = "1";
    return eachVar;
}
function function2() {
    var eachVar = "2";
    return eachVar;
}
function function3() {
    var eachVar = "3";
    return eachVar;
}

function getAllFunctionValues() {
    var functionArray = [function1(), function2(), function3()];
    var allValues = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < functionArray.length; i++) {
        allValues += functionArray[i] + "\n";
    }
    return allValues;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(getAllFunctionValues());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing `eachVar` as a global variable. This means that you can access the variable from any method, thus solving your problem. This can be done like:

```
var eachVar;

function func(){
    eachVar = "value";
}

function other function(){
    console.log(eachVar);    //Will return the value of eachVar
}
```

This ensures that the variable is visible to all methods, not just the individual methods.